Immutable property will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value which cannot be overwritten
I'm working on a new project and to take the advantage of the new features and resources available in Swift/SwiftUI for faster build and to minimize the app size, I'm only using the official libraries. The project is almost completed and I've tried my best to resolve any warnings (deprecation and others) in my codebase. But there is only this one warning I cannot get around.
Here is my struct and I'm using this in a list.
struct RewardObj: Codable, Identifiable{
let id = UUID() // WARNING HERE
var redeemable: Bool? = false
let RewardID: String?
...
}

I've tried to make the UUID() as var id = UUID() but then the data is not decoded and exception is thrown.
I've tried to make it optional and then assign the value as var id: UUID? = UUID() and now only one item is loaded.
Have tried to use computed property as var id = UUID {return UUID()} and using getter as var id = UUID {get{return UUID()}} and in both cases 1/10 times loads the list but makes the app lag and will crash the app within seconds and the memory graph just shoots.
I've this same warning in 4 other places and cannot get around.
Note on potential duplicate
I am aware of the exact same question here, but I've tried the mentioned methods and still cannot resolve.

Does your JSON include an id value?

Either declare id as var or add CodingKeys omitting id. And don't declare all properties schematically optional.

Or ignore the warning. TBH I tend to agree with the some of discussion on the PR that this warning was probably a bad idea

@Paulw11 no, the JSON doesn't have any id value.

@vadian  as i mentioned, I tried changing the id to var but it wasn't working. so the second approach CodingKeys did worked and now my code base have 0 warnings. all perfect. I don't understand exactly why its working so I'll have to see if this will effect the app performance, any energy/memory usage.  thanks.

There is no effect regarding performance/energy/memory.

Awesome. You can put this in the Answer and I'll accept it.

Coding keys is working because it tells the decoder which properties are to be decoded. Since that doesn't include id you don't get a warning that id won't be decoded. You haven't changed the functionality of your code in any way, you have just avoided a compile time warning

Thank you @Paulw11, i figured that out from the PR discussion you mentioned earlier.

Identifiable can use a computed var id for conformance, e.g.
var id: String {
    rewardID
}

Also this rewardID should not be optional since it shouldn't be possible for a reward to exist without an identifier, e.g.
let rewardID: String

